# pseudo steps for parsing http post data

Tags: c++, http-headers, http-post

I am programming a CGI script using c++ where I get post-data from client
If I have post-data like this

```
sam=1&sam2=3&sam5=65
```

what are the steps to parse options where I will put each pair in map object in c++?

I have thought of splitting values by '&' into vector array then splitting each entry in the vector array by '=' and put them in map object, what do you think? Also I want to know what can I do to deal with malformed post-data.

Answer (score 0):

You have the first two steps correct. Separate the name/value pairs at the `&` and separate the name from the value at the `=`. But then you have to [URL decode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) the name and URL decode the value before inserting them into the map.

For example, a `+` in the name or the value should be changed to a space. A `%2B` should be replaced with a space. A `%3D` with an equals sign.

As for malformed post data, it will really depend on your application what you consider malformed. You probably should check for an ambiguous value like `x=2=3`. Is the value `2=3` or `3`? And you can check for a missing name, like `=3` or just `3`.

But the rest is up to the specifics of what's legal in your particular application.